# Why do I get a 500 Internal Server Error and Apache error with exceeded internal redirects?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp, opencart

I've been struggling with an internal redirects issues here.  I'm trying to run a website locally.  It did run, but something changed and I can't figure out what.  http://localhost/store/abc would load OpenCart normally showing a product.  However, it gets 500 internal error now.

The Apache error log shows:
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

The .htaccess file is as follows:  (The site isn't www.abc.com)

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 
# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteBase /store/
RewriteRule ^login$ account/login [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, your last `RewriteRule` rewrites to `index.php`, but that target itself is _not_ excluded in the condition to prevent itself from getting rewritten again. There is your perfect rewriting loop.

Comment: Apart from the fact that I have _not_ idea what that last rule actually is meant to express. You cannot have a path component of a URL that starts with a question mark, so what is that rule meant to do?

Comment: You say "It did run, but something changed"... Things certainly did _not_ work with that rule in place, certainly not. And "something changed" - could it be that the "something" is you having added that rule?

Comment: @arkascha - the last rule (and everything below `RewriteBase`) is part of opencart base and has been there for many years.  Perhaps you don't understand what's happening but there's nothing wrong with any of it. https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/.htaccess.txt

Comment: Sorry I've been away for a while.  Thanks everyone for your feedback.  I'll review and get back to y'all.